# Ask Ubuntu Meta and Ask Ubuntu Reputation is not Synchronized

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, meta

When I had 15 reputation on Ask Ubuntu I wanted to ask something on Meta; I went to Meta, but it said I only had 3 reputation so I could not ask questions. I went to Ask Ubuntu again, but my reputation was still 15.

Thanks!

P.S.: After I waited a day, Meta displayed the correct reputation... ...but still, it's *really* annoying!

Comment: Yeah meta reputation takes about an hour to sync, since there is no independent reputation system for meta and the overhead of syncing it immediately would be too high.

Comment: +1. Few days ago I've also encountered this problem, the reputation gained on Askubuntu wasn't synchronized momentarily with Meta - it lasted about one hour.

Answer (score 2):

The site and all of the network is built around getting groups of people together and keeping them around to exchange what they know with each other.  In the grand scheme of the network, not being able to ask a question on meta immediately after you sign up is probably "bug status: by-design".